# Does Visual Studio create automatically a makefile ? ( vulkan-tutorial.com )

Tags: visual-studio, makefile

In the Windows installation section of https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_Windows we don't explicitly create a makefile, is it done automatically or is it not mandatory?

Edit: I read Visual Studio use some kind of a **solution file** instead of a makefile to build. What is this solution file ? how different is it from a makefile ? and can we create a makefile from a solution file ?

Comment: No, visual studio does not use makefiles. It uses project files and solution files (both are actually XML files). What exactly do you want to do? Build the vulkan project or use it? In the later case, there's a description on how to start further down on the page.

Comment: Thank you. So I was able to build and use the vulkan project like what is described in the page. I was wondering If I can use my own makefile with visual studio or if from a normal project in VS I can automatically create a makefile that do exactly the same job as the project and solution files ?

Comment: No, not easily. There are tools (like cmake or qmake) that can create both makefiles and project files from a kind of "meta-makefile", but these require their own syntax and implementation.